# multicolumn list of acronyms

Tags: acronyms, multicolumn

Is it possible with the `acronym` package to produce two columns of acronyms?
I checked the [package guide](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf), but didn't find any help, should I use a table?
Not really sure on how to proceed. I am using `classicthesis` and have a too long list of acronyms.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage,%
headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,bibtotocnumbered,%
numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty%tablecaptionabove
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{stackrel} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\areaset[5mm]{400pt}{699pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath, amstext, amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{commath}
\graphicspath{{./img/}}

\begin{document}

dum de dum \ac{LS} technique
\section{Acronyms}
\acro{LS}{least squares}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `acronym` package, you can simply include the list of acronyms in a `multicols` environment:

```
\section*{List of Acronyms}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{acronym}[VBLAST]  % longest acronym to fix width
    \acro{WARP}{Wireless Open-Access Research Platform}\acused{WARP}
    \acro{VBLAST}{Vertical Bell Laboratories Layered Space-Time}\acused{VBLAST}
    \acro{LS}{least squares}
\end{acronym}
\end{multicols}
```

Remember that you need to define the acronym with `\acro` before you can use it.  It is thus helpful to include a list like this before the main text, though there are ways around it.

A full example would be:

[image: page]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage,%
headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,bibtotocnumbered,%
numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty%tablecaptionabove
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{stackrel} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\areaset[5mm]{400pt}{699pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{multicol} %<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{amsmath, amstext, amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{commath}
\graphicspath{{./img/}}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%
\section*{List of Acronyms}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{acronym}[VBLAST]  % longest acronym to fix width
    \acro{WARP}{Wireless Open-Access Research Platform}\acused{WARP}
    \acro{VBLAST}{Vertical Bell Laboratories Layered Space-Time}\acused{VBLAST}
    \acro{LS}{least squares}
\end{acronym}
\end{multicols}
%%%%%%%

\acresetall

dum de dum \ac{LS} technique, using \ac{WARP} and \ac{VBLAST}.

\end{document}
```